# Python MySql Select statement. Where colum from Python entry

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I could not figure it out i have tried a lot of possibilities. I want to select a record from a database. Where i take a txt from entry to put in the select statement.

```
def callback():
txt = rentry2.get()
print("If empty there should be nothing ---> " + txt)
if txt != "":
    print("is not empty: " + txt)
    my_cursor.execute("SELECT Name, Discription, Quantity, Price, Barcode FROM stock WHERE Barcode='" + txt + "'")
    result = my_cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result:
        rlbl1 = Label(root, text=row)
        rlbl1.grid(row=3)
        print(row)
```

I have also tried to use this select statement:

```
my_cursor.execute("SELECT Name, Discription, Quantity, Price, Barcode FROM stock WHERE Barcode=%s", (txt,))
my_cursor.execute("SELECT Name, Discription, Quantity, Price, Barcode FROM stock WHERE Barcode='%s'", (txt,))
```

The Value of txt is a barcode: 20083335. I get the txt value from a Tkinter entry box. When i run the code and put a Barcode in the Entry box. It gives me the value of the entry box but i am not getting any result from the sql query. if i enter the barcode into the select statement i get the sql query correct And both are without any results. can someone help me out?
Error:
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '20083335''' at line 1

Comment: Please explain how the solutions are _"not working"_. I recommend also reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: _Always_ use the second approach but with `"... Barcode='%s'"` at the end. I.e. enclose the placeholder in single quotes. This approach protects against SQL Injection. But you also need to clarify what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: What is the value of `txt`?  You're checking for an empty string but might it be `None` etc?

Comment: Use the second form, but be sure you're not getting any errors. "Not working" is not a sufficiently detailed diagnostic to act on. Specific error messages are.

Comment: The Value of TXT is a barcode Like 20083335. When i type in a barcode that's in my database. I dont get the informatie. And i also tried '... Barcode='%s''. If i put the barcode inside the select statement then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near **'20083335'''** at line 1

You can try appending your **txt** through this.

```
my_cursor.execute("SELECT Name, Discription, Quantity, Price, Barcode FROM stock WHERE Barcode=%s",(txt,))
```

**Also** can you double check if your column name for Discription (Description) is really spelled that way? It could've been a typo.

Comment: I have tried the select statement but it gives me no result. if i change fetchall() to fetchone() it gives me an Nonetype error. I have checkt my DB for the description. i have spelled it wrong in the db.

Comment: Okay, what's the value of your variable **txt** before executing the SQL query? can you put a print(txt) before the my_cursor.execute line and check if the result of the print statement matches a barcode stored in your db.

Comment: Thank you paolo. It worked there whas something wrong with the insert query. when you say look at the db its self i figure it out. and looked in to the insert query there was missing one 3 in the db. this would be a lesson for me to check also in db it self. thank you so much

Comment: SinaInan as you mentioned the db issue, do **not** use @Paolo's solution! You expose it to SQL injection where a malicious user can cleverly run [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) in your tkinter app. Re-attempt the parameterized query at end of your post.

Comment: @Parfait What do you mean by:  Re-attempt the parameterized query at end of your post

Comment: Run this instead without quotes around placeholder: `my_cursor.execute("SELECT Name, Discription, Quantity, Price, Barcode FROM stock WHERE Barcode=%s", (txt,))`

Comment: @parfait Thank you for your reply. i will use that.

Comment: I agree with Parfait, the solution I posted above is not for production-grade application. I stand corrected and thank you for your input. Happy coding!